# Which model for panel data with non-random observation numbers per person?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, experiment-design, fixed-effects-model

I did an experiment where I randomly assigned participants to control and treatment group. All performed a task in which they had to illustrate images and then select one image in the end to be payoff relevant. I find a treatment effect on performance on the selected image (selected images in treatment group are on average better than in baseline). Now I want to check whether the treatment has an impact on the selection process (e.g. treatment helps to select better images). Therefore, I would like to estimate on the image level:

chosen ~ treatment performance treatment*performance

chosen: dummy =1 if image was selected

treatment: dummy =1 if image illustrated by participant in treatment group

performance: value between 0-10

and the interaction term is my variable of interest.
However, my problems are that the number of images varies between participants. Therefore, participants with many images are overrepresented in the sample and this variation is systematic as my treatment effect on performance is driven by participants that illustrated few images. I am unsure on how to correct for both issues and which model to use.
Optimally, I would like to examine whether participants in the treatment group select different images than comparable participants in the control group (same number of images, same performance). My idea was to include a random effect (i.e. a random intercept) for the individual participants and maybe a fixed effect for the number of ideas.